# Windows 7 and number of protection rings they use

Tags: windows-7

How many protection rings do the Windows 7 use? I know that Windows XP and previous used only ring 0 and ring 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That hasn't changed. IIRC, OS/2 was the only commercial OS to use the other privilege levels. Having four privilege levels is not portable across multiple CPU architectures, so it is unlikely that a portable OS kernel such as NT would ever use more than two of them.

Comment: XEN uses Ring 1 for paravirtualized DomU IIRC.